# How can I temporarily impersonate a user to open a file?

Tags: asp.net, security, file, impersonation, windows-principal

I would like to temporarily impersonate a domain user account to read in a file on a network drive from an ASP.NET site.

I would rather not set up impersonation for the entire site or set up a mapped drive on the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up using code from [Michiel van Otegem: WindowsImpersonationContext made easy](http://www.vanotegem.nl/PermaLink,guid,36633846-2eca-40fe-9957-2859d8a244dc.aspx) and added an implementation of IDisposable. I found this in [another question about impersonation in ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/impersonation-in-net#125364).

Usage:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContextFacade impersonationContext
     = new WindowsImpersonationContextFacade(
                    Settings.Default.ImpersonationDomain, 
                    Settings.Default.ImpersonationUser,
                    Settings.Default.ImpersonationPass))
                {
                    transactions  = TransactionLoader.Load(filePath);
                }
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Security.Principal;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace MyNamespace
{
    public class WindowsImpersonationContextFacade : IDisposable
    {
        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool LogonUser(String lpszUsername, String lpszDomain,
                                            String lpszPassword, int dwLogonType, int dwLogonProvider,
                                            ref IntPtr phToken);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        public static extern bool CloseHandle(IntPtr handle);

        private const int LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT = 0;
        private const int LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE = 2;

        private string m_Domain;
        private string m_Password;
        private string m_Username;
        private IntPtr m_Token;

        private WindowsImpersonationContext m_Context = null;

        protected bool IsInContext
        {
            get { return m_Context != null; }
        }

        public WindowsImpersonationContextFacade(string domain, string username, string password)
        {
            m_Domain = domain;
            m_Username = username;
            m_Password = password;
            Enter();
        }

        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        private void Enter()
        {
            if (this.IsInContext) return;
            m_Token = IntPtr.Zero;
            bool logonSuccessfull = LogonUser(
                m_Username,
                m_Domain,
                m_Password,
                LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE,
                LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT,
                ref m_Token);
            if (logonSuccessfull == false)
            {
                int error = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
                throw new Win32Exception(error);
            }
            WindowsIdentity identity = new WindowsIdentity(m_Token);
            m_Context = identity.Impersonate();
        }

        [PermissionSetAttribute(SecurityAction.Demand, Name = "FullTrust")]
        private void Leave()
        {
            if (this.IsInContext == false) return;
            m_Context.Undo();

            if (m_Token != IntPtr.Zero) CloseHandle(m_Token);
            m_Context = null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Leave();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't be a fan of this since you have dllimports and other items, and overall you can get by without doing it.

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the process is quite easy, you can use code like this;

```
using System.Security.Principal;
...
// Obtain the authenticated user's Identity
WindowsIdentity winId = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
WindowsImpersonationContext ctx = null;
try
{
  // Start impersonating
  ctx = winId.Impersonate();
  // Now impersonating
  // Access resources using the identity of the authenticated user
}
// Prevent exceptions from propagating
catch
{
}
finally
{
  // Revert impersonation
  if (ctx != null)
    ctx.Undo();
}
// Back to running under the default ASP.NET process identity
```

Your code goes in the "Now impersonating" section.  the KEY is the finally block, this is VERY important.  You can view this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx) article for full details on how this works.

Comment: Can this also be used by passing in a domain, username and password?

Comment: Yes, you just need to create a new windows identity.